# Modal window showing image then error and shows random characters/digits

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm struggling with a modal window in Bootstrap.

I have a PHP `foreach` loop which should display a users uploaded gallery photos. Currently they are opening in a new window and taking users away from my site so I want to change it to have the images open in a modal window.

I've put a modal window in place and it is working so far as it is triggering and displaying the correct image but after about five seconds the image disappears and is replaced by a bunch of characters and digits (looks like some kind of encoding.

The error also removes the close button meaning that you can't close the modal window and return to the page.

**My Code:**

```
<a href="uploads/gallery-photos/<?php echo htmlentities($galleryimage['GalleryPhotoImg'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" target="_blank" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GalleryImgModal-<?php echo htmlentities($galleryimage['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>">
<img class="gallery_thumb" alt="" src="uploads/gallery-photos/<?php echo htmlentities($galleryimage['GalleryPhotoImg'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" width="80px" height="120px" /></a>

<div id="GalleryImgModal-<?php echo htmlentities($galleryimage['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myImgModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button><br />
        <div class="modal-body">
            <img src="uploads/gallery-photos/<?php echo htmlentities($galleryimage['GalleryPhotoImg'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Where am I going wrong?